# To vs For ; their usages and comparisions

Tags: grammaticality

He is extremely important to me. 
Vs 
He is extremely important for me.

The low expectations that the english fans had from  their team proved out to be a blessing  to the team.
Vs 
 The low expectations that the english fans had from  their team proved out to be a blessing  for the team.

Is there any specific rule on when to use TO and when to use For? 
Could anybody explain please !

Comment: No, there is no specific rule. Both _to_ and _for_ are part of grammar rather than the lexicon and they both appear in multiple idioms. Consequently there can be no rule that covers all situations. Or even most situations, since grammatical and idiomatic uses are the most common. Similar remarks apply to other grammatical terms, like _of_ and the articles.

Answer (score 1):

The correct use is:

> He is extremely important **to** me.

and

> The low expectations that the English fans had **for** their team proved  to be a blessing **for** the team.

There is no specific rule that tells you when to use 'to' or when to use 'for' as prepositions, When learning English, the correct use of propositions is one of the more difficult things to come to grips with.  Most native speakers get them right, but only because they have heard them from childhood. Unfortunately, you will only learn how to use them by using them.

If you know someone who is fluent in English, ask them to correct you if you use a preposition incorrectly. Alternatively, read as many English books, magazines or newspapers as you can, and pay special attention to any prepositional phrases. Then, learn that phrase. Do not assume that the preposition that you would use in your native language will be the same as that used in English.

Answer (score 1):

James' answer is generally correct, but I think it is a little less helpful than it might be.

I think that your problem is that you have expressed your question as "when to use *to* and when to use *for*". I suggest that you recast it as "how to use *important* and *blessing*".

It happens to be the case that *important* gets used in the following sentence frames:

> X is important to Y (where Y is a person who judges X as important or not)
>
> X is important for Z (where Z is a process, or situation, which is affected by X.

(There are other possible frames, but these are the ones I am focusing on here).

These frames are as much part of the "meaning" of the word *important* as its definition: a good dictionary will tell you them.